# how to get database sql via hirens boot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7, boot

I have a windows 7 run SQL server (I don't know what is kind of SQL) of my colleague.
My colleague is stopped work.
I don't know password windows, password sql,and sql file,...
I tried crack pass windows using hirent boot but failed, and I can't load partition to remove syskey password.
His machine is sql server.
I can't connection to his machine.

I have a question:
How to get database on his machine without login windows?
Thank all

Comment: you can use any method

Answer (score 0):

If the service of SQL server stopped, you can copy database file and copy in other location, and can attach this file to another SQL server database engine. also you can know version of your SQL server by using SQL Server connection management, and also SQL server query (select @@Version ) if you can execute query.

Comment: "you can copy database file and copy in other location" How to do that?

Comment: His machine has been shutting down.

Comment: I answer only SQL part of your question. you must ask windows question on the http://serverfault.com/ site.